# Node.js EveryAuth Get Google Email Address

Tags: node.js, oauth, everyauth

I am attempting to retrieve the google email address when making an OAuth2.0 call to google, using EveryAuth NPM lib.  Has anyone managed to get the email to return using EveryAuth?

```
everyauth.google
  .entryPath('/auth/google')
  .callbackPath('/auth/google/callback')
  .appId('216450162097.apps.googleusercontent.com')
  .appSecret('8b6yf2nznWHgAu7iKNyGn-0F')
  .scope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'])
  .findOrCreateUser( function(session, userAttributes) {
    console.log(userAttributes);  })
  .redirectPath('/');
```

The scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email causes exception:

Error: 
Error
401
(Not Found)!!1

display:block;height:55px;margin:0 0 -7px;width:150px}* > #g{margin-left:-2px}#g img{visibility:hidden}* html #g img{visibility:visible}*+html #g img{visibility:visible}
      
[image: Google]

**401.**
That's an error.

There was an error in your request.
That's all we know.

at [object Object].fail (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/lib/promise.js:50:15)
    at EventEmitter. (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/lib/modules/google.js:58:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at EventEmitter._respond (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:127:12)
    at EventEmitter._fireEvents (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:131:52)
    at /Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:115:19
    at IncomingMessage. (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:205:5)
    at IncomingMessage. (/Users/thegoleffect/Documents/Projects/Spoondate/nitrous/node_modules/everyauth/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:113:32)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [google](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope) the scope and the api end point are slightly different, which confused me a little.  If you make the change to your google.js to the following, the google Auth2.0 api will return the email address of the user.

```
  .fetchOAuthUser( function (accessToken) {
    var promise = this.Promise();
    rest.get('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email', {
      query: { oauth_token: accessToken, alt: 'json' }
    }).on('success', function (data, res) {
      console.log(data);
      var oauthUser = { email: data };
      promise.fulfill(oauthUser);
    }).on('error', function (data, res) {
      console.log(data);
      promise.fail(data);
    });
    return promise;
  });
```

Comment: works and I see i get the user email in the log. However it does not create a new user? Do i need to write a custom findOrCreateUser function?